# Scalable placement of fixed position div on large screen

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a one column layout with several divs stacked vertically. The topmost div however should move into a second column and have a fixed position once the screen is wide enough.

Currently I use something like in this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/L3u3xqdu/1/

html:

```
<div class="red">
</div>
<div class="blue">
</div>
```

css:

```
.red {
  background-color: red;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;  
}
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .red {
    position: fixed;
    left: 500px;
  }
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 400px;
  height: 2000px;
}
```

My question is: Is there a more scalable solution that does not require knowing the width of the column to hardcode the position of the fixed div? I have to adapt that offset every time I add something to the one column. I am searching for some CSS magic or maybe a small framework or library that I can use.

My other libraries that I use are: react, stylus, lodash, jquery, normalize.css

Comment: Use `right:10px` instead of `left:500px` in media query. if you want to fixed in right side.

Comment: I do not want it stick to the right side. It should stick to right side of the left column.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/u09dpgot/

An extra wrapper div:

```
<div class="colwrap">
  <div class="red">

  </div>
  <div class="blue">

  </div>
</div>
```

flex css (order changes the order of the html elements visually in the browser):

```
.colwrap {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.red,
.blue {
  flex:0 0 400px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 400px;  
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 2000px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .red {
    order:2;
  }

  .blue {
    order:1;
  }
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: This looks like a good start. I would be happy if we could unhardcode the 900px. Is that somehow possible? Because now between (2*400=) 800px and 900px window width the order is red->blue instead of blue->red.

Comment: The flex basis can be set in px, percent, ems whatever, and you can set a min-width or a max-width on the div as well if you need to. Have fun with it.